# Add data from one table into another based on another value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, opencart2.3

I need to take data from one table and add it to another. This is to link a supplier to a product, however it's not a simple query, so I'm not sure if this can be done.

I have a table which is xxx_product and then another table which is xxx_product_to_vendor.

I need to take each record in xxx_product and add it to xxx_product_to_vendor.

xxx_product_to_vendor has three columns.

```
product_to_vendor_id
product_id
vendor_id
```

- product_to_vendor_id must auto increment in numbers as it's the record number.
- product_id must be taken from the product_id in table xxx_product.
- vendor_id must be assigned as following. If supplier_id in xxx_vendor is 4 then vendor_id in xxx_product_to_vendor must be 1.

Here are images of my two tables.

[image: xxx_product table]

[image: xxx_product_to_vendor table]

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my issue without the need of a query. I simply exported the table as CSV for MS through phpmyadmin and deleted the columns I didn't need and updated the data in excel. Imported the edited sheet into the other table without any issues.